# unit testing iOS function with dispatch

Tags: ios, unit-testing, dispatch-async, expectations

I'm working with unit testing for the first time and I'm lost with some specific cases.

Despite reading a lot I'm confused about how to test a function like this in iOS:

```
func myFunction() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
          // Tasks to do in background
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            // Get the results
            // Update UI
         });
    });
}
```

I've read about "expectations" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations?language=objc), but I don't know how to use them. I guess I should have to call
expectation.fulfill(), but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `myFunction` doesn't accept a completion handler in which you can call `fulfill`, it isn't testable.

You would need to refactor the function to accept an optional completion handler closure and to invoke it once the work is complete. You can then pass a closure when you call the function from your test in which you can `fulfill` the expectation.